# Conceptual and Physical database modeling tool for MAC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, database-design

I usually making RoR apps on mac, and I need tool where I can make conceptual and physical database models for PostgreSql and MySQL.

I found SQLEditor, but it's really minimal. I need something more powerful like PowerDesigner for Windows that I used.

Any suggestions? 
P.S. It can be commercial!

Comment: Just as a note that this would be different on MySQL and PostgreSQL since PostgreSQL has inet and macaddress types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), works great on Mac, Linux and Windows.